# React history - is there a way to remove duplicate entires when going back?

Tags: html

Currently for my back button I'm using window.history.back() which, in itself is working properly. My issue is with an iframe that I have for refreshing sessions, example

```
<iframe src="https://example.com/some/path?gcp-iap-mode=SESSION_REFRESHER" style="width:0;height:0;border:0; border:none;"></iframe>
```

Path in my project represents current url, so it keeps changing every time I change locations. Now, with the source the iframe has, it keeps throwing 404 and getting into my history so instead of clicking back button once, I have to do it at least two times - first times it fails as it tries to reach randompath?gcp-iap-mode=SESSION_REFRESHER and then it goes to proper path.

My question is, is there a way for me to check the "back" value, to see if the "back" value has a specific query (for example gcp-iap-mode part), or check if it's the same as a current location (duplicate) so I can skip that entry (and couple of back steps) and go back to a different path in history stack?

Comment: Is there a way for your code or whatever it is to do redirects instead of navigations? I.E. REPLACE instead of PUSH? This was the history stack is maintained and hitting back from any page you redirected to goes back to the page before all the iframe redirect business. If it's relevant, can we see the code used to manage the navigation? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I figured out the solution. Seems it was very common issue and solution was simple - add  a key prop to iframe to 'remount' it instead of rerendering it. That would stop the src from being pushed into the history stack and go back works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems an issue like this is common in iframes. I tried looking at it from a wrong perspective, by looking for ways to change history where the only thing that needed to be changed is the iframe itself.
Basically when we only change the src attribute of the iframe it gets rendered again and again and the src gets pushed to history stack. What we needed here was the iframe to unmount and the soultion to all of that was pretty simple - add a **key** prop to the iframe.
This is a blog page that helped me, so if somebody wants to read more:
https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/react-iframes-back-navigation-bug/